# Htaccess redirect with all versions of Internet Explorer except the 9

Tags: apache, internet-explorer, .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to redirect through htaccess all versions of Internet Explorer than version 9, the last, to another page. But it still fails.

I've tried things like:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "MSIE [4-8]" [NC,OR]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://sitioweb.com [R=301,L]
```

Can you help?

Answer (score 1):

Removing the `,OR` from your rules above works for me:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "MSIE [4-8]" [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://sitioweb.com [R=301,L]
```